# evince 3.4.0 can NOT display some simplified chinese fonts

Tags: fonts, pdf, evince

I have installed `acroread-fonts` and `xpdf`, but still failed to display those fonts.
I also tried to use `acroread`, failed too.

I use evince 3.4 in ubuntu12.04.2 amd64 arch. How to do with it ? Thanks

Below is screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try installing/running:

`sudo apt-get install xvfb xfonts-base xfonts-75dpi xfonts-100dpi`

`sudo apt-get install xfonts-intl-chinese`

and finally

`sudo apt-get install xfonts-wqy`

Logout/Login - Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, but these fail too.